# What is the vb.net equivalent of switch expressions in c# 8

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

What is the vb.net equivalent of switch expressions in c# 8 ?
See this sample code from msdn. It shows an error message while i try to convert it to vb.net.

```cs
public static class SwitchExample
{
    public enum Directions
    {
        Up,
        Down,
        Right,
        Left
    }

    public enum Orientation
    {
        North,
        South,
        East,
        West
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var direction = Directions.Right;
        Console.WriteLine($"Map view direction is {direction}");

        var orientation = direction switch
        {
            Directions.Up    => Orientation.North,
            Directions.Right => Orientation.East,
            Directions.Down  => Orientation.South,
            Directions.Left  => Orientation.West,
        };
        Console.WriteLine($"Cardinal orientation is {orientation}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Its a `Select Case` and it doesnt support expressions like that.

Comment: You can do something like: `Dim ori As Orientation Select Case direction 
    Case Direction.Up  
        ori = Orientation.North
End Select ` and so on for each one.

Comment: VB.NET's switch statement has always been more powerful than C#'s. Perhaps it didn't need a make-over.

Comment: I think this is new in C# 8. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions

Comment: @Enigmativity: Neither did C# - this is a good example of syntax porn developed by bored language designers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent in VB has about the same level of complexity, so you have to wonder about the usefulness of using switch expressions for this in the first place:

```
Dim orientation As Orientation
Select Case direction
    Case Directions.Up
        orientation = Orientation.North
    Case Directions.Right
        orientation = Orientation.East
    Case Directions.Down
        orientation = Orientation.South
    Case Directions.Left
        orientation = Orientation.West
End Select
```

See my comment about 'syntax porn'.